# How can I shift these binary numbers in C?

Tags: c, binary

I want to shift the variable `x` so the result would be: 0000 0000 0000 1111

```
    int x = 1111 0000 0000 0000;
    int z = x >> 12;

    printf("%d", z);
```

But it is not working.
First, I can not compile the program because I get the error:

> "error: expected ',' or ';' before numeric constant"

And second, when I delete the whitespace between the numbers in the `int x`, I get the result "-162425". But I want the result to be: "0000 0000 0000 1111".

It feels like the program doesn't know that `int x` should be seen as a binary number, not as an integer.

Should I use something else than `int`, is there any data type so I can get the result I want?

Comment: Use hexadecimal. `1111 0000 0000 0000` -> `0xF000`, it's an easy way to write binary numbers.

Comment: gcc has its own extension statring with 0b